# jQuery dynamically input fields not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was following a tutorial (which I modified a bit) here: [code](http://jsfiddle.net/hMJEy/210/)

In JSFiddle the code is working neat, however, on the real page which code is below, is not working, I've been struggling but I cannot find an answer :-( so any help is appreciated.

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $('.multi-field-wrapper').each(function() {
            var $wrapper = $('.multi-fields', this);
            $(".add-field", $(this)).click(function(e) {
                $('.multi-field:first-child', $wrapper).clone(true).appendTo($wrapper).find('input').val('').focus();
            });
            $('.multi-field .remove-field', $wrapper).click(function() {
                if ($('.multi-field', $wrapper).length > 1)
                    $(this).parent('.multi-field').remove();
            });
        });

    </script>
    <title>AQUATAP - Gestor de Información - Añadir Pedido</title>
</head>

<body>

    <form role="form" action="add_order.php" method="POST">
        Cliente:
        <input type="text" name="cliente" id="buscar">
        <br>
        <hr />
        Fecha de salida:
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="salida_pronosticada" value="male">
        En el día
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="salida_pronosticada" value="male">
        2 días
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="salida_pronosticada" value="female">
        3 días
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="salida_pronosticada" value="female">
        5 días
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="salida_pronosticada" value="female">
        1 semana
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="salida_pronosticada" value="female">
        Otro
        <input type="text" name="salida_pronosticada_otro">
        días
        <br>
        <hr />
        <label>Stuff y cantidad</label>
        <div class="multi-field-wrapper">
            <div class="multi-fields">
                <div class="multi-field">
                    <input type="text" class="buscar_prod" name="input_referencia[]">
                    <input type="text" name="input_cantidad[]">
                    <button type="button" class="remove-field">
                        X
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="add-field">
                Add field
            </button>
            <input type="submit" name="guardar" value="Guardar" />
        </div>
    </form>

</body>
```

So well... any help is appreciated. 
I've been playing around and I think i might be missing something... like if the script didn't start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are saying that your code is working on the page you showed us.

Just try this :

```
http://api.jquery.com/ready/


$( document ).ready(function() {
$('.multi-field-wrapper').each(function() {
            var $wrapper = $('.multi-fields', this);
            $(".add-field", $(this)).click(function(e) {
                $('.multi-field:first-child', $wrapper).clone(true).appendTo($wrapper).find('input').val('').focus();
            });
            $('.multi-field .remove-field', $wrapper).click(function() {
                if ($('.multi-field', $wrapper).length > 1)
                    $(this).parent('.multi-field').remove();
            });
        });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Add Your Code Inside `document.ready`

```
$(function(){
$('.multi-field-wrapper').each(function() {
        var $wrapper = $('.multi-fields', this);
        $(".add-field", $(this)).click(function(e) {
            $('.multi-field:first-child', $wrapper).clone(true).appendTo($wrapper).find('input').val('').focus();
        });
        $('.multi-field .remove-field', $wrapper).click(function() {
            if ($('.multi-field', $wrapper).length > 1)
                $(this).parent('.multi-field').remove();
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your code in [**document-ready**](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler

```
$(document).ready(function() {

});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.multi-field-wrapper').each(function() {
        var $wrapper = $('.multi-fields', this);
        $(".add-field", $(this)).click(function(e) {
            $('.multi-field:first-child', $wrapper).clone(true).appendTo($wrapper).find('input').val('').focus();
        });
        $('.multi-field .remove-field', $wrapper).click(function() {
            if ($('.multi-field', $wrapper).length > 1)
                $(this).parent('.multi-field').remove();
        });
    });
});
</script>
<title>AQUATAP - Gestor de Información - Añadir Pedido</title>
</head>
```

You need to kick things off with a document ready function.

"A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready." jQuery detects this state of readiness for you".

Taken from http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/